# inserting a file without quotes mysql

Tags: mysql, import, quotes

I have a rather large csv file (half a billion rows) in which one field is a string.  However, the format that this file is provided in does not include '' around the string.  Is there a way to import this into a MySQL database without writing a concatenation program to break the data down add the quotes and recombine the data for a line by line insert statement?

Comment: Why do you think quotes are necessary? What have you tried?

Comment: When I attempt to import a small section of the file i get a 1054 Unknown Column 'None' in field list.  From what I've read it seems that not having quotes around a string might cause this issue.

Comment: Side Note:  I've been attempting for the past several days to import the file using LOAD DATA INFILE, but I keep running into issues with Losing Connection to the Amazon RDS I'm testing.  So, I figured I would test a smaller piece of data.  The LOAD DATA INFILE method works on smaller pieces of data just fine, so that isn't my issue.  So, I'm testing a different method hoping that I can find a way to import the file.

Comment: How are you importing the data? Are you using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: I'm attempting to just use the import wizard in Workbench to see if that might resolve the issue (though I suspect it would take considerably longer if it uses an insert statement).

Comment: The " 1054 Unknown Column 'None' in field list" happened to me when the import file contained data for a column which did not exist in the destination table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only import data at one time. You can use the MYSQL Workbanch to import a csv file.

You'd better do NOT insert data line by line. This way is inefficient.

You can perform sql statement like this:

> INSERT INTO MyTable(ID,NAME) VALUES(7,'003'),(8,'004'),(9,'005');